# input shape RNN in keras

Tags: python, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I'm new to Keras and I am trying to create my network which is a time series data with 2 features. Here are the details of my training input and output:

```
train_input.shape= (1, 21, 20) (21 time-step, 20 (2*10) 10 training-set with each 2 features)

train_output.shape = (1, 21, 10)
```

Here is the code:

```
model = keras.models.Sequential([
    keras.layers.SimpleRNN(4 ,input_shape = (trainset.shape[1],2), return_sequences=True, use_bias= False, activation = "tanh"), 
    keras.layers.TimeDistributed(keras.layers.Dense(1))])  
print(model.get_weights())
model.compile(loss= "mean_squared_error" , optimizer= keras.optimizers.SGD(), metrics = ['mse'])
saved_files="\\RNN_based_statespace\\models\\weights-{epoch:02d}-{val_loss:.6f}.hdf5"
checkpoint = keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(saved_files, monitor='val_loss', verbose=0, save_best_only=True, save_weights_only=True, mode='auto', period=1)
callbacks_list = [checkpoint]
history = model.fit(trainset , output_train, epochs = 100, batch_size=1 , validation_data = (validationset,output_valid), callbacks=[callbacks_list]
Prediction = model.predict(testset)
```

But I get the error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer sequential_1: expected shape=(None, None, 2), found shape=[1, 21, 20]
```

How do I pass the correct parameters?

Comment: You said your input has 20 features, but you pass `input_shape = (trainset.shape[1],2)`.
It should be 20 instead of 2, I guess?

Comment: my input has 2 features, but because I have 10 train-set the dimension of input is changed to 20

Comment: but why do you concatenate the training sets in the last dimension and not in the first one?

Comment: I had a code with 1 training set with 2 features and 21 time step(21,2) and then it is reshaped to (1,21,2), then I defined a looped to increase my training set to 10, so the (21,2) matrix changed to (21,20), and then I reshaped it to (1,21,20) . Am I doing it incorrectly? How I can define the loop to concatenate the training in the first one?

Comment: The first dimension must indicate the sample, i.e., your training data should have the shape `(10,21,2)`.
You can get this, e.g., considering you have training samples A0,A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8,A9, each of shape `(1,21,2)`, then you can get the proper format by `trainset = np.concatenate((A0,A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8,A9), axis=0)`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, it resolved the issue